# Can't see 5Ghz networks - WiFi Link 4965AGN

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a laptop that has an Intel Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN, according to the spec, it's compatible with 802.11a, 802.11b, 802.11g and 802.11n "Draft" networks. I have a dual band Tp-Link Archer C50 and on the 5GHz band it supports 802.11a devices but on the computer with the WiFi Link, it can't see the 5Ghz network. (In mode 6 802.11a/b/g or mode 1 802.11a).

I've installed the Intel Pro Set drivers from Intel's website (driver version 13.4.0.139).

OS: Windows 10 Pro 1809 x64

Router wireless standard support: 802.11n/g/b (2.4Ghz) 802.11ac/n/a (5Ghz)

Comment: Can you see the 5GHz network on other devices, eg mobile 'phone or another PC?

Comment: Yep, all of my other 5Ghz compatible devices (802.11n/ac and one 802.11a) can see the network.

Comment: Exact model of laptop?

Comment: Fujitsu Lifebook S6410 is the laptop that can't see the 5Ghz network

Comment: Googling "4965AGN 5GHz" gives a lot of references, but I can't say which might apply to you: [this link](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/697827/cant-see-80211a-networks-intel-wifi-link-4965agn/) and [this](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/intel-4965agn-cant-connect-to-5ghz.377548/) look promising.

Comment: What about your Laptops 5G working on other networks? Does it work? Has it ever worked? Or is this issue only with your Archer C50?

Comment: @AFH, the references don't seem to help

Comment: @Sickest The laptop doesn't seem to see other 5G networks at all, so I think it's either a driver issue with the WiFi module or an issue with the module

Comment: When booted in Ubuntu Mate, the WiFi module still can't find any 5Ghz networks

Comment: Sorry the references didn't help, though they do indicate that there are difficulties with 5GHz support on that chip. As a footnote to your last comment, the BroadCom chip in my Lenovo laptop connects to 5GHz with Windows, but not in Ubuntu Mate (which I normally use). My investigations seemed to show it's a driver issue, so I have learned to live with 2.4GHz speeds. If you're desperate for 5GHz, you might consider side-stepping the issue and buying a WiFi USB dongle.

Comment: 5g is over rated anyway. I personally rarely ever use it. I’d prefer distance over speed any day

Comment: @AFH It's fine, I'm not desperate for 5Ghz, it's more of a "nice to have" in my opinion